# Fragment inside a tab won't show on initial load

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, xamarin.android

I have a `DialogFragment` showing 2 tabs, and each tab shows a fragment, created dynamically and added via `ChildFragmentTransaction` .

The problem is, on the very first load of my `DialogFragment`, everything is shown **except** the fragment, but after switching between tabs, fragments are shown properly. The same happens when changing between landscape and portrait, first time it loads, only the tabs are shown, but when switching, the fragment appears.

Here's the code for setting up the tabs.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Game_Over_Dialog1, parent, false);

        PlayerTabs = v.FindViewById<TabHost>(Resource.Id.PlayerTabs);
        GameOverOk = v.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CloseGameOver);
        PlayerTabs.Setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = PlayerTabs.NewTabSpec(player1.Name);
        spec.SetContent(Resource.Id.PlayerDataContainer);
        spec.SetIndicator(player1.Name);
        PlayerTabs.AddTab(spec);

        spec = PlayerTabs.NewTabSpec(player2.Name);
        spec.SetContent(Resource.Id.PlayerDataContainer);
        spec.SetIndicator(player2.Name);
        PlayerTabs.AddTab(spec);

        Dialog.SetTitle("Game Over");
        Dialog.SetCancelable(true);

        GameOverOk.Click += delegate { Dialog.Dismiss(); };
        PlayerTabs.TabChanged += PlayerTabs_TabChanged;
        ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(Resource.Id.PlayerDataContainer, player1Frag).Commit();
        return v;
    }
```

I've trying to place the `ChildFragmentTransaction` in various places, before and after setting up tabs, in `onStart` , I've also tried programmatically changing the selected tabs, but nothing worked.

Any ideas on why I'm unable to see the fragment when first showing the dialog? Any workarounds, or am I missing something trivial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `PlayersTab.setCurrentTab(0)` (the argument is the index number, so 0 or 1 in this case) should do the trick. I'd add it after the second

```
    PlayerTabs.AddTab(spec);
```

Comment: `spec` is a `TabSpec` it doesn't have `setCurrentTab`. I'll try with `TabWidget` in case it was just a misspell.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Sorry, should be called on `PlayersTab`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!